# Add class to previous element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have slider and i want to get previous div and to add class="prev" into this

```
<div class="mb-panel" >
    <div class="mb-inside">
        <div id="container_1" class="mymasonryclass masonry">Example 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-panel current">
    <div class="mb-inside">
        <div id="container_2" class="mymasonryclass masonry current">Example 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I want a class like "mymasonryclass masonry prev" for a previous div and in a **dynamic way**.

I have used jquery for that.

I have tried below code:

```
$('.mymasonryclass').each(function(index, value){
    var cname = $(this).attr('class');
    if(cname.indexOf('current') != -1)
    {
        var div= $(this).parent('div');
        var prev= $(div).prev();
        var output;
        var x = $('.mb-inside');
        $('.mb-inside').each(function(index,value){
            var t1 = $(this).find('div.current');
            if(t1.length > 0)
            {
                var output = $('.mb-inside')[index-1];
                if(index-1 > 0)
                    output.css('float', 'right');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But its not working.

Comment: Where is the jQuery code you used?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php

Comment: `$(#container).addClass('prev')` ? Don't what you want exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried below code and it works

```
var a = $('.mb-panel.current').prev();
var b = a.find('.mymasonryclass.masonry');
if(b)
b.css('float', 'right');
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the above structure, this might be what you're after:

```
var $previousPanel = $('.mb-panel.current').prev(); // get previous panel
$previousPanel.addClass('prev'); // add class to panel
$previousPanel.find('.masonry').addClass('prev'); // add class to inner div too
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/5dt7f/).

Comment: It is in the example. Maybe you should clarify what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use my live [[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/liyakat/SB6N3/][1]

it is for just one static div you can make it dynamic as per your requirement

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#container_2").hover(
function () {    

   $(this).parents(".mb-panel").prev().find('div.mymasonryclass').addClass('prev');

  },
  function () {
    // $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

});